# (tcbdoc)marginnote ignores twoside option

Tags: koma-script, tcolorbox, marginnote

I am using KOMA-Script to manage my page layout and need to use `twoside=semi`. For footnotes etc. I use `scrlayer-notecolumn`, which is perfectly configurable for my task. As you may see in the following picture `\tcbdocmarginnote` (and the usual `\marginnote`) ignore the `twoside=semi` setting.

So my question: How can I force `\tcbdocmarginnote` to use the right margin (only right, not outer)? That equals: How can I force `\tcbdocmarginnote` to obey `twoside=semi`?

[image: my problem]

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,DIV=calc,BCOR=1mm,a7paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe} % for demonstration
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn,xparse,tcolorbox,marginnote} % for implementation
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\begin{document}
    This is a test\tcbdocmarginnote{\tcbdocnew{1.0}}\\[2em]
    Marginnote\marginnote{Test}\clearpage
    This is a test\tcbdocmarginnote{\tcbdocnew{1.0}}\\[2em]
    Marginnote\marginnote{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `twoside=semi` is twoside with oneside margins. So the result is as expected. Use `twoside=false` if you don't want twoside effects.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I want and need the effect for my document (a book), because I use to typeset footnotes, caption, figures etc. in the margin. That works very well, but my document also includes some documentation code and this is the only part of the document ignoring my margin layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`marginnote` does understand `\reversemarginpar`. You can automate the usage of `\reversemarginpar` on even pages using `\ifthispageodd`:

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi,DIV=calc,BCOR=1mm,a7paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe} % for demonstration
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn,xparse,tcolorbox,marginnote} % for implementation
\tcbuselibrary{documentation}

\let\originalmarginnote\marginnote
\renewcommand{\marginnote}{%
  \ifthispageodd{\normalmarginpar}{\reversemarginpar}\originalmarginnote
}

\begin{document}
    This is a test\tcbdocmarginnote{\tcbdocnew{1.0}}\\[2em]
    Marginnote\marginnote{Test}\clearpage
    This is a test\tcbdocmarginnote{\tcbdocnew{1.0}}\\[2em]
    Marginnote\marginnote{Test}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately `\reversemarginpar` activates the reverse behavior for all notes on a page.